# Drupal form with custom Ajax

Tags: 7, ajax

Objective: Once client update any form's field, it will update database. (Will not need submit button to update the form). Example: I change name field value from Peter to Tom. It will automatically update database.

```
    function ajaxFunction(getName){
    var ajaxRequest;
        var getVariable = "name="+getName;
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('name');
            ajaxDisplay.value= ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "name.php", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.send(getVariable); 
}

</script>
```

I create a file call name.php and load the file to /sites/all/modules/custom/name.php

I can send the value $_POST["name"]. Which mean everything is good. I think....

My problem is name.php seem cannot connect to database. I use db_select to do the testing and I dun get any result. I predict there is php error and I believe db_select is not recognized.

```
  $query= db_select('particular', 'n')
   ->fields('n')
   ->condition('nid', '111111','=');

   $result=$query->execute();
   foreach ($result as $record) {
      echo $record->name;
   }
```

May I know how to meet my objective?

Comment: You're bypassing all the Drupal APIs with this code. You should be using the #ajax API of the Form API to handle this. It is much, much more secure than what you are doing. Take a look at the examples module (http://dgo.to/examples) for examples of how to use this.

Comment: @Jaypan, Thanks for your reply. However, The link dun help me much.

Comment: Did you download the module and look through the code? It's how most developers learn to do things like #ajax.